# 'SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement' this error occured because I did 'import random'

Tags: python, statements

I am trying to create a guessing game and I am quite new and I keep getting this error and the IDLE points to the fact that I typed in 'import random'

I've also tried the 'import random*' instead of 'import random' and then it shows invalid syntax, I honestly dont know what to do at this point.

```
import random
n = random.randint(1,10)
tries = 0
start = app(n)
def app():
    g = input('Do you want to play?')
    if g == 'Yes':
        print('ok')
        print(start)#Here we start the game
    if g == 'No':
        print('too bad')

def game(n):
    d = input('Pick a number between 1 and 10')
    if d == n:
        print('Very nice, took you', tries, 'tries')
        a = input('wanna go again?')
        if a == 'y':
            app()

    elif d > n:
        d == input('Try guessing lower')

    elif d < n:
        d == input('Try guessing higher')
```

Comment: if your code is formated like in the question, it looks like you have an indentation problem at the beginning

Comment: Just because this is a common error, your script isn't named `random.py` by any chance? If that's the case, you're trying to import your own script.

Comment: Define the functions before the 3 first commands. A function should be defined before any command calls it, at least when the code looks like yours (a single file)

Answer (score 0):

Don't do the code on the python shell, create a module, so File + New File or Ctrl + N to create a new file, then do the code there and your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

Besides having problems with possibly working directly with the shell, here are a few issues with your codes.

1. `start = app(n)` should be `start = game(n)`. `app` doesn't take in any input. Or perhaps you have to redefine your app function to take in `n`.
2. You should only call game after you define it.
3. Typo in print statement, `tries` is not a variable.
4. Possible indentation.
5. If the player answer he wants to play again, you might like to use a loop to restart the game using a new random number.

```
    import random


    def app():
        g = input('Do you want to play?')
        if g == 'Yes':
            print('ok')
            print(start)#Here we start the game
        if g == 'No':
            print('too bad')

    def game(n):
        d = input('Pick a number between 1 and 10')
        if d == n:
            print('Very nice, took you', d,  'tries')
            a = input('wanna go again?')
            if a == 'y':
                app() # I think you want to add in code to restart a game.

        elif d > n:
            d == input('Try guessing lower')

        elif d < n:
            d == input('Try guessing higher')

    n = random.randint(1,10)
    tries = 0
    start = game(n)
```